# how to map json object to pojo, if json object have key like "track-id" as "-' cant be used

Tags: json, jackson

How to map JSON object to POJO, if JSON object have key

> "track-id" 
>   and POJO have String trackId.

Answer (score 0):

in jackson we have annotation @JsonProperty for this, we just have to use it in our pojo like

@JsonProperty("tracking-id")

private String trackingId;